# Find N non-neighbor elements in array so that sum is maximum

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse

I have a 2d array (int[][]) that represents an area. The integers in each point stand for the value of the same.

The objective is to pick N points in the 2d array so that the sum of their values is the maximum possible. There's the added difficulty of not being able to pick 2 points that stand together, so if you pick one then the 8 spaces arround are banned.

[Here's an example for a given map with N=5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vq4DR.png)

Here's how I'm planning to structure it:

```
public static int[][] getBestPoints(int[][] matrix, int N) {
    int[][] bestPoints = []; //the best option picked from the candidates
    Map<Int,int[][]> candidates = new HashMap<Int, int[]>{};

    //candidates is a map that stores the possition of N elements and the 
    //total sum of their represented values

   //Here there'd be a loop section that searchs for all the best 
   //combinations and stores them in the var candidates

    return bestPoints; //solution for the example picture {{1,3},{1,5},{2,1},{4,2},{5,4}}

}
```

Any ideas on where to start? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is that the complete problem description.   Something feels missing

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because because the OP has shown no effort and it seems like a homework question.

Answer (score 0):

Each cell in these matrices could be stored in a class like this:

```
import java.util.Comparator;

public class Cell {

private int row;
private int column;
private Integer value;
private Integer cost;

public static final Comparator<Cell> SUM_COMPARATOR = (Cell c1, Cell c2) -> c1.getSum().compareTo(c2.getSum());

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int hash = 7;
    hash = 71 * hash + this.row;
    hash = 71 * hash + this.column;
    return hash;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj) {
        return true;
    }
    if (obj == null) {
        return false;
    }
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
        return false;
    }
    final Cell other = (Cell) obj;
    if (this.row != other.row) {
        return false;
    }
    if (this.column != other.column) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

public int getRow() {
    return row;
}

public void setRow(int row) {
    this.row = row;
}

public int getColumn() {
    return column;
}

public void setColumn(int column) {
    this.column = column;
}

public Integer getValue() {
    return value;
}

public void setValue(Integer value) {
    this.value = value;
}

public Integer getCost() {
    return cost;
}

public void setCost(Integer cost) {
    this.cost = cost;
}

public Integer getSum() {
    return cost+value;
}
}
```

The above Cell class stores both cost and value, and a List then contains the information of both matrices. Use Collections.sort() (and Collections.reverse()) to sort them using the SUM_COMPARATOR implemented in class Cell, which compares the sum of cost and value. Iterate the sorted elements and compare them for distance check like this:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class Test {

private static final int NUMBER_OF_CELLS_AROUND_EXCLUDED = 1;

public static void main(String[] args){

    List<Cell> cells = new ArrayList<>();

    // load prices and values in each Cell instance here...

    // and sort them
    Collections.sort(cells, Cell.SUM_COMPARATOR);
    Collections.reverse(cells);

    // then iterate both lists, which contain the
    List<Cell> chosen = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Cell cell : cells){
        if (notTooClose(cell, chosen.get((chosen.size()-1)))){
            chosen.add(cell);
        }
        if (chosen.size() == 5)
            break;
    }
}

private static boolean notTooClose(Cell cellA, Cell cellB){
    int rowDist = Math.abs(cellA.getRow()-cellB.getRow());
    int colDist = Math.abs(cellA.getColumn()-cellB.getColumn());

    return rowDist > NUMBER_OF_CELLS_AROUND_EXCLUDED && 
           colDist > NUMBER_OF_CELLS_AROUND_EXCLUDED;
}
}
```

Comment: The tricky part is how you can't just sort by high because of the wrinkle added by not allowing side by side values. Consider the value 100 surrounded by the value 99, and then outside of that a ring of 1's. Really the issue becomes one of dynamically considering 3x3 areas (shifting to see how different solution candidates change the max/min).

Comment: Thank you very much, I like the idea of creating a cell class, it makes it easier to find the row/column possition of each element. You might have noticed I changed the description of the problem, I feel like the priority is to search for the best N elements in the 'values' 2d array. The 'Price' array is only neccesary if there's multiple combinations of cells that add up to the same maximum

Comment: @Quaternion  I don't think that'd be an issue, since the class cell has an attribute for rows and columns that you can get in order to make sure they are not side by side

Comment: @Duermeduerme what Guillem has provided is essential however sorting isn't the hard part (at least to most Java programmers), you can certainly then compare to see that they are not side by side, but as my example points out, going by only a sort and my 5x5 example (100 in middle, ring of 99, then an outer ring of 1's) the solution set would be: 1, 1, 100, 1, 1 which is clearly incorrect. The maximal would be: 1, 99, 99, 99, 1 (this is simply a very trivial example). So this material is essential but the most challenging aspect of the problem remains.

Comment: @Quaternion I've modified the answer to include the distance restriction between solutions, as well as to provide sorting based on the sum of cost and value for a given cell's coordinates.

Comment: If this answer did solve your question, could you mark it as solved?